# Captured URL parameters in form

Tags: django, django-users

I am using Userena and I am trying to capture URL parameters and get them to my form but I'm lost how to do this.

What I would like to do in my template is:

```
<a href="/accounts/signup/freeplan">Free Plan</a><br/>
<a href="/accounts/signup/proplan">Pro Plan</a><br/>
<a href="/accounts/signup/enterpriseplan">Enterprise Plan</a><br/>
```

And then in my urls.py

```
url(r'^accounts/signup/(?P<planslug>.*)/$','userena.views.signup',{'signup_form':SignupFormExtra}),
```

Then, ideally, I'd like to use that planslug in my forms.py to set the user plan in the profile.

I'm lost how to get the captured URL parameter into the custom form. Can I use the extra_context, do I have to override the Userena signup view?

Answer (score 14):

If you use class based views, you can overwrite the def get_form_kwargs() method of the FormMixin class. Here you can pass any parameters you need to your form class.

in urls.py:

```
url(r'^create/something/(?P<foo>.*)/$', MyCreateView.as_view(), name='my_create_view'),
```

in views.py:

```
class MyCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = MyForm
    model = MyModel

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super( MyCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        # update the kwargs for the form init method with yours
        kwargs.update(self.kwargs)  # self.kwargs contains all url conf params
        return kwargs
```

in forms.py:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, foo=None, *args, **kwargs)
        # we explicit define the foo keyword argument, cause otherwise kwargs will 
        # contain it and passes it on to the super class, who fails cause it's not
        # aware of a foo keyword argument.
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print foo  # prints the value of the foo url conf param
```

hope this helps :-)

Comment: And If you don't use class based views?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the url in your template using -

```
{% request.get_full_path %}
```

(see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_full_path) for more info).

However if you just want to get the `planslug` variable then pass it from the view to the template and access it in the template (it's available in the view because it's a named parameter in the url) -

```
def signup(request, planslug=None):
    #
    render(request, 'your_template.html', {'planslug':planslug}
```

and then in your template you get it with -

```
{% planslug %}
```

If you're using class based views then you'll need to [override get_context_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/#adding-extra-context) to add the `planslug` variable to your context before you pass it to the template-

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(get_context_data, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context['planslug'] = self.kwargs['planslug']
    return context
```