# get parameter from url into hidden parameter of form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a CreateView where I want to create a new price for a product. The product detail page has a button to change the price which leads to a new page like `...\partprice\X` where X is the id of the product. A product can have multiple prices, which is the reason why I am using a `CreateView`. Is the only way to grab the `part_id` from the URL (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990659/captured-url-parameters-in-form))?

In the forms.py:

```
class PPriceFormset(ModelForm):
    required_css_class = "required"
    
    class Meta:
        model = PPrice
        fields = ("price", "customer", "date", "part")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST' 
        self.helper.layout = Layout(Row(Column('price'),
                                        Column('customer')),
                                    Submit('submit', 'Save price', css_class='btn-primary'),
                                    Field("date", type="hidden"),
                                    Field("part", type="hidden"))
```

I want to add the `X` from above into the hidden field "part". In the view I already have it:

```
class PPrice(CreateView):
    model = PPrice
    template_name ="gap/pprice_update.html"
    form_class = PPriceFormset
    success_url = reverse_lazy('part-list')

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(PPriceCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        kwargs['part_id'] = self.kwargs.get("part_pk")
        return kwargs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite easy, the class needed an initial value that could be passed on to the form via `get_initial`.

```
class PPriceCreateView(CreateView):
    model = PPrice
    template_name ="gap/pprice_update.html"
    form_class = PPriceFormset
    success_url = reverse_lazy('part-list')

    def get_initial(self):
        return {"part": self.kwargs["part_pk"]}
```