# How can I prepopulate a form in class based views with url variable <str:>

Tags: python, django, forms, populate, web-frameworks

As the question says,I'm trying to prepopulate a form with a url varible, by this I mean that the form fills with the variable that is in the url. I was trying to use the get initial function, but it's not working, so I will share my code so you can see what's going on and what mistakes I'm doing

views.py

```py
class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'app1/createpost.html'

    def get_initial(self, **kwargs):
        
        #Returns the initial data to use for forms on this view.
        initial = super().get_initial()

        initial['stock'] = self.kwargs.get('sym')

        return initial

        def form_valid(self, form, sym):
            form.instance.author = self.request.user
            return super().form_valid(form)
```

models.py

```py
class StockNames(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.symbol

        
    

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 255)
    header_image = models.ImageField(null = True, blank = True, upload_to = 'images/')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = RichTextField(blank = True, null = True)
    #body = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='coding')
    snippet = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'blog_posts')
    stock = models.ForeignKey(StockNames, null=True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('app1:article-detail', args=(self.id,))
```

forms.py

```py
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title','category', 'body', 'snippet', 'header_image', 'stock')

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Title', 'length':'100px'}),
            #'author': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'value': '', 'id':'elder','type': 'hidden'}),
            #'author': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'category': forms.Select(choices = choice_list,attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Choices'}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'snippet': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'stock': forms.Select(choices = choice_list,attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Choices'})
            
            
        }
```

urls.py

```py
app_name = 'app1'

urlpatterns = [
    path('add_post/<str:sym>',AddPostView.as_view(), name='addpost'),

]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with get_form_kwargs in views.py ([Captured URL parameters in form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990659/captured-url-parameters-in-form)) :

You can override the `get_form_kwargs` and pass the `stock` to kwargs dictionary. Then in your `__init__()` method, set your field on the form.

views.py:

```
class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'app1/createpost.html'
    stock = None
    
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(AddPostView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        stock = self.kwargs.get('sym')
        kwargs.update({'stock': stock})
        return kwargs
```

forms.py:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        stock= kwargs.pop('stock')
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['stock'] = stock
```

Comment: and how do I apply that in the get_initial form?

Comment: You don't have to. your code is in 2 places. Crytal clear example : https://gist.github.com/vero4karu/ec0f82bb3d302961503d

Comment: Hey man, I tried it and it says __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stock'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220096/discussion-between-eric-martin-and-sebastian-nin).